# Truncate bidirectional text

Tags: unicode, text-rendering, arabic-support

for a project I am currently working on my own text rendering engine. Currently I am stuck on how to truncate bidirectional text properly in case it does not fit within the available text box.

I imagine the following behavior should apply:

(Text is always "Hello Matthew" in different languages)

- All Left-to-right text:

  > Hello Matthew
  >   →
  >   Hello Mat...
- All Right-to-left text (I just copied this from Google translate so please excuse any misspelling):

  > مرحبا ماثيو
  >   →
  >   مرحبا م...‏
- Mixed RTL and LTR text:

  > Matthew مرحبا‎‏
  >   →
  >   Mat... مرحبا‎‏

Is there any standard that describes how the truncation should be done and how to do it? (Currently I image to always truncate the end of the string in memory order and append the ellipsis to the end in memory order. But I think there is also a Left-to-right / Right-to-left mark after the ellipsis necessary sometimes based on ...?)

Comment: In unicode, memory order truncation is the correct way. As you see in your example, you can read the text and you see the dots where text is truncated. One will read the last line rightly: "Hello Mat...". So I do not understand what you are looking for.

Comment: BTW: I do not find official way neither in https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/tr9-41.html nor in https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/ (but browsers should be able to support truncation, so you may need to check how they solved the problem)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I am looking for confirmation that this is the correct way first of all. Also, the last example will not display properly when you just cut the text and append the ellipsis, you also need to add a Left-to-right mark after it. In the case you have e.g. "Name: <Arabic Name>" and <arabic name> is truncated you would need to add a Right-to-left mark. I imagine this will get more complicated as you mix this up a bit, so an algorithm would be nice.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the issue is with mixed LTR and RTL texts like above